# What is the best way for selecting 2 row from table in one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a table like following

```
TABLE_A
ID           PERSON_ID    NAME         GRADE
----------   ----------   ----------   ----------
1            1            NAME_1       10
2            1            NAME_1       20
3            2            NAME_2       30
4            2            NAME_2       40
...
```

in this table, for each name there is exactly two rows (two grades).
I want to make a query which results like following

```
RESULT
PERSON_ID    NAME         GRADE1       GRADE_2
----------   ----------   ----------   ----------
1            NAME_1       10            20
2            NAME_2       30            40
```

What is the best way for this.
I can use self join but I think this is not correct method

Comment: How do you calculate GRADE1 and GRADE_2 ??

Comment: Ooo. I think lase name will be Name_2.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: You tag MySQL and Postgresql, and accept an SQL Server answer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found best answer for PostgreSQL in this link
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html
In PostgreSQL there is the `crosstab(text)` function.

> The crosstab function is used to produce "pivot" displays, wherein data is listed across the page rather than down. For example, we might have data like

```
row1    val11
row1    val12
row1    val13
...
row2    val21
row2    val22
row2    val23
...
```

> which we wish to display like

```
row1    val11   val12   val13   ...
row2    val21   val22   val23   ...
...
```

> The `crosstab` function takes a text parameter that is a SQL query producing raw data formatted in the first way, and produces a table formatted in the second way.
>   The `sql` parameter is a SQL statement that produces the source set of data.
>   This statement must return one `row_name` column, one `category` column, and one `value` column. `N` is an obsolete parameter, ignored if supplied (formerly this had to match the number of output value columns, but now that is determined by the calling query).
>   For example, the provided query might produce a set something like:

```
row_name    cat    value
----------+-------+-------
  row1      cat1    val1
  row1      cat2    val2
  row1      cat3    val3
  row1      cat4    val4
  row2      cat1    val5
  row2      cat2    val6
  row2      cat3    val7
  row2      cat4    val8
```

> The `crosstab` function is declared to return `setof record`, so the actual names and types of the output columns must be defined in the `FROM` clause of the calling `SELECT` statement, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('...') AS ct(row_name text, category_1 text, category_2 text);
```

> This example produces a set something like:

```
           <== value  columns  ==>
 row_name   category_1   category_2
----------+------------+------------
  row1        val1         val2
  row2        val5         val6
```

For more read section **F.35.1.2.** in URL entered top of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY as the other person suggested.

Or you can make a join.

```
select t1.person_id, t1.grade as grade1, t2.grade as grade2
from TABLE_A t1 join TABLE_A t2 on t1.person_id=t2.person_id and t1.id!=t2.id
```

This JOIN joins all the rows with the same person, but not the rows with the same id so you filter out the duplicates.

Comment: interesting approach :) i think you should use `.. and t1.id<t2.id` instead of `!=` so grade1 will be the first and grade2 the second

Comment: Yes, you're right it would be would be better that way if we consider that the grades are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SQL SERVER

```
; WITH CTE AS(
SELECT PERSON_ID, NAME, GRADE AS GRADE_1, 
LEAD(GRADE) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) AS GRADE_2 
FROM TABLE_A
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE GRADE_2 IS NOT NULL

RESULT SET:

PERSON_ID    NAME         GRADE_1       GRADE_2
----------   ----------   ----------   ----------
1            NAME_1       10            20
2            NAME_2       30            40
```

Comment: Is this a MySQL or Postgresql answer (or both)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, and if all names have exactly two records, and the first grade is the one with the lower id and the second grade the other, then you could use a query like this one:

```
select
  person_id,
  name,
  group_concat(grade order by id) as grades
from
  table_a
group by
  person_id,
  name
```

then if you want to separate grades into two new columns you could use SUBSTRING_INDEX:

```
select
  person_id,
  name,
  substring_index(group_concat(grade order by id), ',', 1) as grade1,
  substring_index(group_concat(grade order by id), ',', -1) as grade2
from
  table_a
group by
  person_id,
  name
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the topic starter didn't mention the ORDER of grades and "there is exactly two rows (two grades)" I think the easiest way:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, 
       MAX(NAME) as NAME, 
       MIN(GRADE) as GRADE1, 
       MAX(GRADE) as GRADE2
 FROM TABLE_A
 GROUP BY PERSON_ID
```